# Solution Output Directory

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

The project that I'm currently working on is being developed by multiple teams where each team is responsible for different part of the project. They all have set up their own C# projects and solutions with configuration settings specific to their own needs. However, now we need to create another, global solution, which will combine and build all projects into the same output directory.

The problem that I have encountered though, is that I have found only one way to make all projects build into the same output directory - I need to modify configurations for all of them. That is what we would like to avoid. We would prefer that all these projects had no knowledge about this "global" solution. Each team must retain possibility to work just with their own sub-solution.

One possible workaround is to create a special configuration for all projects just for this "global" solution, but that could create extra problems since now you have to constantly sync this configuration settings with the regular one, used by that specific team. Last thing we want to do is to spend hours trying to figure out why something doesn't work when building under global solution just because of some check box that developers have checked in their configuration, but forgot to do so in the global configuration.

So, to simplify, we need some sort of output directory setting or post build event that would only be present when building from that global, all-inclusive solution. Is there any way to achieve this without changing something in projects configurations?

**Update 1**
Some extra details I guess I need to mention:

We need this global solution to be as close as possible to what the end user gets when he installs our application, since we intend to use it for debugging of the entire application when we need to figure out which part of the application isn't working before sending this bug to the team working on that part.

This means that when building under global solution, the output directory hierarchy should be the same as it would be in Program Files after installation, so that if, for example, we have Program Files/MyApplication/Addins folder which contains all the addins developed by different teams, we need the global solution to copy the binaries from addins projects and place them in the output directory accordingly.

The thing is, the team developing an addin doesn't necessary know that it is an addin and that it should be placed in that folder, so they cannot change their relative output directory to be build/bin/Debug/Addins.

Comment: WHy do you wish to build again can't you just let the projects build as usual and collect the binaries produced and reference them from the global solution?

Comment: @Rune FS And how do you make the solution to collect and copy all binaries to the global output directory automatically after they all have been built?

Comment: Depends on what the goal of the global solution is. I'm guessing you have some build tasks to perform that is in it's own project. Is that correct?

Comment: @Rune FS. Well, we need that solution for debugging of the entire application. Sometimes we encounter some sort of an error and we don't know exactly which part of the project isn't working properly. To counter these issues we have a QA team that recreates the problem while debugging under global solution and when it figures out which part of the application isn't working properly, it sends this defect to the team responsible for that part of the application so that they can fix it.

Comment: Then the proposed solution in my answer will work just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One very simple way would be to create the solution. Include all the projects and add a project (or more) to handle the global solution build tasks. The projects in the global solution should then have a reference to the projects they need and then let Visual Studio handle how to get the binaries from each project. They will (under normal circumstances) be copied to the output folder of the build project. So the project added specifically for the global build tasks would have a copy of all the referenced projects

Another way would be to create a global MSBuild script that references the rest of the build scripts. Each project is on it's own a MSBuild script

**EDIT**

From the comments it would seem that there are two categories of projects. One that needs building and one that does not.

For those that need building reference them as projects in the aggregating project for those that do not require building add them either as references or add the dll as resources.

Using the later change the property of the Build action to None and copy to output directory to Copy if newer

In both cases you now have all dll's in the output directory you can then have a post build action on the aggregating project **moving** the dlls that should be in a specific folder (ie not in the output folder)

Comment: Hmm, if I just add another empty project, then that project needs to build something, like a .dll or .exe. Is there a way to have a project that doesn't produce anything as a result of it's build operation?

Comment: You said you are building an application/system that the QA guys can run. Then the project representing the application/system is the aggregating project. If you already have a project that aggregates you don't need to add anything new. If you don't have an aggregating project atm then QA has nothing to run. So which one is it I'm a bit confuse as to me reading your comments states it's both :)

Comment: The aggregate project can't use all of the projects as references. Some of them act as loosely coupled addins. They should also be placed not directly into the output directory, but into some subfolder in the output directory, like build/bin/Debug/Addins/MyCustomAddin1. I guess I could use post build script in the aggregate project to copy addins, but then we would be required to build aggregate project each time we update addin project, which could be time consuming. I was hoping there would be some way to build only addin and VS will be able to figure out where it needs to copy binaries.

Comment: Marked as answer since it solves my problem, although I'm still looking at MSBuild scripts as a possible second solution.

Comment: You are already using MSBuild script since project files are just MSBuild scripts

Answer (score 2):

The key here is that team is responsible for a deliverable. That deliverable is a collection of binaries. So the "global" solution ... or "product that uses the deliverables from teams" is interested in ensuring that all of the 'current deliverables' work together. That is, that you have a deliverable from the collaborative effort.

So this begs a few questions. Do the team deliver what they consider to be a 'release'. This may be automatic in the build system. If it builds and all tests pass then publish it.

What you are looking for is a team publishing or promoting a release. The source code is how you got there, the binaries are the result. Each team controls what binaries it considers to be a release (this may be automated by the build system).

Not exactly what you asked, but I hope it is the answer that leads to the right questions to give good results.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the practice of [**Continuous Integration**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) and the usage of a **Build Server** with scripted builds. This is an indispensable instrument when developing different parts of an application as a team, and your problems are a great illustration of the reason why.

Comment: That bears little relevance to the problem described.  Using continuous integration or a build server on an existing solution/project doesn't change anything about the build output.

Comment: @DanPuzey maybe we understand the question differently. As far as I understand OP's problem, CI is exactly what would help here.

Comment: In what way would CI help to change the output paths of projects when combined into a larger solution?  Or alternatively, what problem do you think that the poster faces that CI solves?  Your answer is a blanket "CI is good and you should use it," but you've not really explained why.

Answer (score 0):

You've not mentioned if you use a Version Control system. I've found in practise that each developer maintains his/hers/their teams configuration and builds locally on there machine, since you don't check *.suo or *.user files most of the personal configuration only affects the individual team member.

On a completely seperate machine check-out the same code from all repositories and compile the project on the build machine (this can be completely automated). This maintains your build servers independance.

Don't worry about it being a "Solution". You can easily build multiple solutions one after the other.

Since the output path is relative (and probably "bin\Debug") it'll get built wherever you check it out to. If you want all the binaries in the same output folder you could tweak the output path on every configuration to match. Something like "....\bin\Debug" (obviously this affects where the projects get built to on the local machines but it might not matter). That way multiple projects would get built the same target output.

You could also include a seperate setup build on the build server which isn't on each developers local machine to package up the final product.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but aren't build configuration settings stored in .csproj files?

Comment: Yes, but with relative paths/references, that's a good thing since it means you don't have to manually synchronise build configuration options. I see that line in my answer is misleading so I'll change it.